# measure for binary grouping frequencys

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Is there a way to quantify how binary sequence groupings differ in how they alternate between $0$ and $1$?
This is probably best explained through an example of what I have in mind.

For example
$$
a)\, 0 1 0 1 0\\
b)\, 1 1 0 0 0\\
$$
where $(b)$ is assigned some higher value?

some more examples of what I have in mind;
$$
a)\, 1 1 0 0\\
b)\, 0 1 1 0\\
f(a) = f(b)$$ for w/e $f$ turns out to be

$$a)\, 1 0 0 1\\
b)\, 0 1 1 0$$
$$f(a) < f(b)\\$$
$$
a) 1 1 0 1\\
b) 0 1 1 0\\
f(a) > f(b)
$$
In short I'd like to find a way to quantify how "close" non-zero binary digits are grouped together. Where closer groupings are assigned higher values.
I don't mean a probability frequency as these patterns are strictly deterministic. That is, the sequences repeat themselves if they are extended to infinity.

I thought information entropy or hamming distance (relative to 0000..) measures would quantify this behavior but they do not seem to take into consideration groupings and are more related to the number of 1's vs zeros.

Does there exist a way to quantify these relationships?

Comment: How would you compare $010101$ to $001100$? How about $10101010$ vs $00000111$? Or even $00000011$? There are all sorts of measures you could define, but which one would be best for your purposes depends on how strongly you want to rank longer strings over shorter strings,

Comment: Could you provide some examples? Just so I could see what is out there? In terms of your other question I would rank $0000111>001100=000011>010101$ Just don't know where to look for something that measures this.

Comment: So how many "$01010\ldots$" would it take to match a single $11$? How many $011011\ldots$ to match a single $111$?. You don't have to look for something. Just make up something that works for you. For example, pick a sequence $(p_n)$, and then let $c_k$ be the number of $1$-strings of length $k$ in your number. For instance $101011011101101$ would have $c_1 = 3, c_2 = 2, c_3 = 1$ and $c_k = 0$ for $k > 3$. Then you can define the strength of your string as $$S := \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_kp_k$$How fast $p_k$ grows determines how important longer $1$-strings are as compared to repetitions of shorter

Comment: This is probably a dumb question but $p_k$ is just some arbitrary function/weight of importance I would decide to attribute per value of $k$ correct?

Comment: I think that is what your last statement is referring to.. but would like to be sure.

Comment: Yes. You pick the $p_k$ depending on what fits your need. If you would like $11$ to be "stronger" than any number of repetitions of $01$, and similarly for higher reps, then you might want to do something like this instead: $$S := \sum_k 2^k\left(1 - \left(\frac 12\right)^{c_k}\right)$$ Then the first singleton $1$ counts half of a pair $11$. But each additional singleton is itself worth only half the previous. So no matter how many singletons you add up, it is never quite as much as a single $11$, and similarly for higher reps.

Comment: Thank you. I'll see what works best, thanks for the help and intuition.